# GUI to Change Multiple Working Directories in Script ( R )

Tags: r, user-interface

So, I have code that compares two piles of data to one another, 
e.g., before diet plan and after diet plan.

Because the people using the code are, frankly, code-phobic, I am trying to make it as easy to use as possible.

I want them to be able to use a GUI to select the path to the working directories, e.g.,

```
    a. Select Before Working Directory:  [             ]↓ 
    b. Select After  Working Directory:  [             ]↓ 
    c. Select Output Location         :  [             ]↓
```

The path from a would need to be stored as a string in the script as I use it in the following manner:

```
  a = "path1"
  b = "path2"
  c = "path3"

  setwd(a)
  <<code>>
  <<code>>

  setwd(b)
  <<code>>
  <<code>>

  setwd(c)
  write.csv( df, "file_name")
```

Rcmdr seems like one option, but it does seem very overkill for my purposes.

---

UPDATE:
I came across I `dlgDir` of the `svDialogs` package as well -- very handy.

Comment: Just use file.choose() to set each directory.

Comment: Out of the scope of your request, have you considered `shiny` or one of several other non-*R*-gui interfaces? Often, it can be nice to provide a simple web-friendly interface, if your analytical methodology is fairly predictable and non-*R*-console dependent.

Comment: Ah. I should have thought of it as I have used RStudio. Thanks for this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can do something like this using base `file.choose()` and `dirname()`:**

```
cat("a. Select Before Working Directory:") 
a <- file.choose()
a <- dirname(a)
cat("b. Select After  Working Directory:")
b <- file.choose()
b <- dirname(b)
cat("c. Select Output Location:")
c <-  file.choose()
c <- dirname(c)
```

**or maybe even `tcltk`:**

```
require(tcltk)
pathA <- function() {
  a <<- tk_choose.dir()
}
pathB <- function() {
  b <<- tk_choose.dir()
}
pathC <- function() {
  c <<- tk_choose.dir()
}

#create UI with three buttons
tt <- tktoplevel()
buttonA <- tkbutton(tt, text = "a. Select Before Working Directory:", command = pathA)
buttonB <- tkbutton(tt, text = "b. Select After  Working Directory:", command = pathB)
buttonC <- tkbutton(tt, text = "c. Select Output Location:", command = pathC)


tkpack(buttonA)
tkpack(buttonB)
tkpack(buttonC)
```

Comment: tcltk is pretty cool. At any rate, this is great. Thank you so much!